# what is the static in generic java?

Tags: java, generics, static

What is the "static" in generic for example:

```
    class Test
{
    // A Generic method example
    static <T> void genericDisplay (T element)
    {
        System.out.println(element.getClass().getName() +
                           " = " + element);
    }


// Driver method
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
     // Calling generic method with Integer argument
    genericDisplay(11);

    // Calling generic method with String argument
    genericDisplay("GeeksForGeeks");

    // Calling generic method with double argument
    genericDisplay(1.0);
 }
}
```

has a static  in it, while:

```
    class Test<T>
{
    // An object of type T is declared
    T obj;
    Test(T obj) {  this.obj = obj;  }  // constructor
    public T getObject()  { return this.obj; }
}
   
// Driver class to test above
class Main
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        // instance of Integer type
        Test <Integer> iObj = new Test<Integer>(15);  
        System.out.println(iObj.getObject());
   
        // instance of String type
        Test <String> sObj =
                          new Test<String>("GeeksForGeeks");
        System.out.println(sObj.getObject());
        iObj = sObj; //This results an error  
    }
}
```

this doesn't ?

Is it because in the 1st example the class is class Test, while in the 2nd example it is class< T> ?

Or because in the 1st example the generic method is in the same class as the main method that's why it has the static? Because consider the following code:

```
public class GenericMethod {
   public static < E> void printArray(E[] inputArray) {
        for(E element : inputArray) {
             System.out.println("%s", element);
         }  
         System.out.println();
   }
}


public class Test {
   public static void main(...) {
      Integer[] intArray = {1,2,3};
      System.out.println("Array integerArray contains:");
      printArray(intArray);
   }
}
```

the GenericMethod class still has static in it although it aren't in the same class with main?

Comment: One’s a generic method, the other a generic class. The fact that it’s a static method is really irrelevant. Note both your generic methods are somewhat pointless as they don’t add anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference comes from here:
When you have a class `Test<T>` the type `T` is locked for the class and you can use it for method parameters and return types.

In the other example, you have a class `Test`, which doesn't have a generic type `T`. Therefore the method `static <T> void genericDisplay (T element)` declares the type `T` so that the compiler knows about it.

The syntax `<T> void method()` is not related to the use of `static` keyword. Here the use of `static` means that a method can be called *statically*, without instantiating an instance of a class: `GenericMethod.<Integer>printArray(intArray)` or `GenericMethod.printArray(intArray)`.

In your example with `Test<T>` you are instantiating an instance of `Test<Integer>` and calling methods on the instance.